# Find the general solution to the nonhomogeneous equation $x^2y''+xy'-n^2y=x^m$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question asks find the general solution to the non-homogeneous equation $$x^2y''+xy'-n^2y=x^m, x>0$$
Where $m$ and $n\neq0$ are any real numbers such that $m^2\neq n^2$.
The hint says to substitute $y_h=x^λ$ which then gives$$λ(λ-1)x^λ+λx^λ-n^2x^λ=0$$
Its simple substitution but I'm getting confused on the terms. How does $x=λ$ and $x^2=λ(λ-1)$

Comment: Is $y$ a function of $x$ alone?

Comment: A different hint: Try to let $x=e^t$ and set $v(t)=y(x)$. You will get something (hopefully) familiar for $v(t)$.

Comment: Simplify your expression to $x^\lambda(\lambda^2-n^2)=0$

Comment: $y$ is a function of only $x$

Comment: After you've substituted, your equation simplifies to $(\lambda(\lambda-1)+\lambda-n^2)x^{\lambda}=0$.  This needs to hold for every value of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** Your expression simplifies to
$$λ(λ-1)x^λ+λx^λ-n^2x^λ=x^λ(\lambda^2-n^2)=0.$$